# Fatal Error Array index out of Range

Tags: arrays, swift

My code is getting information (names , latitudes, longitudes, and cities they are in) from a local .txt file. It works fine up until certain rows, then gives this "Array index out of range error" at certain rows. Below is my code and the txt file:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("wifi (1)", ofType: "txt")
let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
if filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(path!){
    do{
        let fullText = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let readings = fullText.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
        for i in 1..<readings.count{
            let data = readings[i].componentsSeparatedByString("\t") as [String]
            dictClients["name"] = "\(data[0])"
            dictClients["lat"] = "\(data[1])"
            dictClients["lng"] = "\(data[2])"
            dictClients["city"] = "\(data[3])"

            arrayClients.addObject(dictClients)
            print(dictClients["name"])
        }
    }catch let error as NSError{
        print(error)
    }
}
```

A sample of the .txt file (where it would cut out on the BBs the Crescent line):

> Sky Court Shopping Shannon    -8.8818377  52.710461   Clare\ Perys Hotel
>   Limerick  -8.6484363  52.6629662  Limerick\ BBs Jetland Shopping
>   Center    -8.6966707  52.6734915  Limerick\ Statoil
>   Caherdavin    -8.6456267  52.6650273  Limerick\ BBs The Crescent Shopping
>   Centre  -8.6480104    52.6405294 Limerick\

Comment: Why don't you print each record before you process it, and have a look at the record it fails on? My suspicion is it that it fails on dictClients["city"] = "\(data[3])", because the index record is missing a field. Print the record out to the console and I bet the problem will iquickly be found.

Comment: Even better, have a check that makes sure the data array has 4 items in it - otherwise the data is incomplete. My guess is you have a new line at the end of your file - therefore the last component is an empty string.

Comment: Yes, originaluser, that would probably both find and to some extent fix the problem - he can just chuck bad data away (I would assume). Or he could try and massage it programmatically.

Comment: oreiginaluser2 , How would I check for four items in it?

Comment: `if data.count == 4 {...}`? Or you could fill any gaps in the array with an error string like "entry not found". Or use a guard, and throw an error that you can catch. Depends entirely how you want to handle bad data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your file has some empty lines - probably, at the end. You need to guard against that.

In addition, `dictClients` appears to be a shared object which you add to `arrayClients` multiple times. This would create an unexpected behavior after you fix the exception - all entries will match the last entry. You should fix it by creating a new dictionary on each loop iteration:

```
for str in readings {
    let data = s.componentsSeparatedByString("\t") as [String]
    // Skip lines that do not contain exactly four tokens
    if (data.count != 4) {
        continue
    }
    let dict [String:String] = {
        "name" : data[0]
    ,   "lat"  : data[1]
    ,   "lng"  : data[2]
    ,   "city" : data[3]
    }
    arrayClients.addObject(dict)
    print(dict["name"])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here `for i in 1..<readings.count`
If the reading array is empty, but your loop always start with index 1 thats why it shows the error. You should start your loop from 0. like

```
for i in 0..<readings.count
```

Comment: `readings` is an array of strings from file. It looks like OP wants to skip the first line for some reason. This, however, would not cause the out-of-range error when `readings` is empty: you would get a different exception - `Can't form Range with end < start`

Comment: Its okay. I found a solution. It filters results to see if they have four objects first